# Data insertion in msacces from javascript

Tags: javascript, ms-access

I just wanna ask what is wrong or missing in my code, i cannot insert data in my database. I also searched in this site and used the code there but its not inserting data. Thank you in advance!

```
    var adVarWChar = 202;
    var adParamInput = 1;
    var fnamer = document.getElementById('firstn');
    var lnamer = document.getElementById('lastn').value;
    var usernr = document.getElementById('uname').value;
    var passwr = document.getElementById('pword').value;




var con = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");
var constring = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = Z:\JS\javascriptdb.accdb";
var cmd = new ActiveObject("ADODB.Command");
cmd.ActiveConnection = con;
con.Open();
cmd.CommandText = "Insert into register(firstn,lastn,usern,passw)Values(?,?,?,?)";

cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("?",advarWChar,adParamInput,50,fnamer));
cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("?",advarWChar,adParamInput,50,lnamer));
cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("?",advarWChar,adParamInput,50,usernr));
cmd.Parameters.Append(cmd.CreateParameter("?",advarWChar,adParamInput,50,passwr));

cmd.Execute();
con.Close();
```

Comment: Is this in a browser? What does the Developer Console (F12) tell you?

Comment: Named parameters are not supported. You might try to replace your  `Values(fn,ln,un,pw)` with `Values(?,?,?,?)` but the order of the parameter in your cmd.Parameters collection is important in that case

Comment: When i pressed f12, it seems there is no error showing. I see, so i need to change the values to (?,?,?,?) and in parameter append, i need to also change the variables to "?" ?Thank you sir/maam

Comment: I already changed the variables to "?" just like what i have edited in my post, but it still cannot insert data.